# How to find the type of a element in a list in and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a dynamic list as given below

```
List<dynamic> question = [" Elephants", "are", "the", 1, "land", 2, "on", 3];
```

I'm using a listview.builder to use this list on the screen to populate ui. What I want is to identify the int and show container with a red color and if it is string i want a container with blue color. How can i identiy the type of elements in the list

```
ListView.separated(
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
if (question.indexOf(int)) { // how to identify the type
return Container(color:Colors.red);
} else {
return Container(color:Colors.blue);
}
},
separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(
width: 6,
),
itemCount: question.length),
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `is` for type checks.

```
if(question[i] is int){

} else if(question[i] is String){

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Dart, you can check the type of an object using the `is` keyword or the `runtimeType` property.

1. Using the `is` keyword: The is keyword is used to check if an object is of a certain type. It returns a boolean value indicating whether the object is of the specified type or not.

   ```
   if(question[i] is int) {

   } else if(question[i] is String) {

   }
   ```
2. Using the `runtimeType` property: The runtimeType property returns the actual runtime type of an object.

   ```
   if(question[i].runtimeType==String) {

   } else if(question[i].runtimeType==int) {

   }
   ```

Comment: `runtimeType` is of type `Type` and never going to be `List` or `int`.

Comment: @inkredusk `runtimeType` is of *type* `Type`, but its *value* can be `int` (which is why it would need to be tested with `==` instead if with `is`).  It can *sometimes* be `List` (which really means `List<dynamic>`), but you shouldn't rely on it since `List` is an abstract class and the actual implementation class could be something else.

Comment: ok. well noted and thanks @jamesdlin

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is` operator to check `Type` of any object

Example:

```
List<dynamic> question = [" Elephants", "are", "the", 1, "land", 2, "on", 3];

for(var element in question) {
   if(element is String) {
      // current element is String. Handle accordingly
   } else if (element is int) {
      // current element is int. Handle accordingly
   } else {
      // unknown or any other type. Handle accordingly
   }
}
```

To use it in `UI` file you can check following example:

```dart
ListView.separated(itemBuilder: (context, index) => question[index] is String ? Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.green,
   ),
   child: Center(
     child: Text("String"),
    ),
  ) : question[index] is int ? Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    child: Center(
     child: Text("int"),
    ),
  ) : Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    ),
    child: Center(
     child: Text("Unknown"),
    ),
  ), 
    itemCount: question.length);
```